# TFS Get latest version - delete local files when they deleted from remote TFS Repository

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, tfvc

We are migrating a tfs repository (az devops cloud) to tfs (another organization, cloud also.)

when getting latest version from the source repository, the files that were deleted from the remote repo are not getting deleted in the local workspace.

We are using visual studio to manage our tfs files.

Our repository is something like 800 GB. so cloning again is not an option.

Steps i did :

1. Get Latest version - **Did not delete the local files (if they deleted remote)**
2. Compare (local to remote) - checkout - did not delete local files.

any thoughts here ?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you clean the workspace first before everything else.

Retry getting latest version after you clean.

In visual studio, you can check for pending deletes, if you find any, check them in to complete the deletion.

Then you can compare workspaces if none of the above work. Compare local and remote.

A last resort would be to manually delete the files (DANGEROUS move, make sure you have backup)

Comment: What is the meaning of cleaning my workspace ? how ? is there a simple way to cleanup ?

Comment: Right-click on the solution in Visual Studio and select "Advanced" -> "Clean Workspace." This will delete all of the local files that are not part of the source control.

Comment: Somehow my visual studio has no solution in it., is it fixable quickly ?

Comment: I'm unsure if you would require a solution or not as I do not know the exact structure of your repo. But in any case, if the repo does not have a solution, you can still do it via Command Prompt. Nagivate to the workspace directory on your computer. Run the tf workspace command `tf workspaces` Note the name of the workspace you wanna clean. Run `tf workspace /delete [WorkspaceName];[Owner]`

Comment: Example: `tf workspace /delete MyWorkspace;User1`

Comment: This command will delete my workspace.. i will need to clone again the whole repository as i understand

Comment: So i just make a little POC under a folder, it definitely deleted the entire workspace,

Comment: Can you get latest version and check for pending deletes then? That's the only alternative except for comparing and manually deleting files